# Style a comma separated html text without adding lists

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div class="working-days">Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday</div>

<div class="weekends">Saturday, Sunday</div>
```

Is that possible to Style, for example, Wednesday as it is without adding lists for each day?

Here is what i have tried but it styles all the text in the div and not one by one:

```js
$( ".working-days:contains('Monday')" ).css( "text-decoration", "underline" );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="working-days">Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday</div>
```

Comment: Text nodes do not have a `style` property. What style are you trying to apply to the text?

Comment: It's called markup language for a reason. If you have a list, use `ul` or `ol` and make your life easier.

Comment: @Marco can you show an example?

Comment: You can not apply CSS classes by comma separated. Thus you have to wrap each day with html container (such as span) and apply the styles separately on each other either by class or by 'style' attribute.

Answer (score 1):

`Text` nodes doesn't have a `style` property, you can wrap the text that you want to style inside a `span`

```
<div class="working-days">Monday, Tuesday, <span class="txtStyle">Wednesday</span>, Thursday, Friday</div>
```

Comment: okay. Actually i want to style all days, so i have to add 7 spans

Comment: @csandreas1, If you data is available then you could create them dynamically using a loop

Answer (score 0):

you can directly apply css in a span tag

```html
<span style="color: #ff0000">Monday</span>
```

Comment: i know i just have to do it with js

Comment: then you have to apply a class and then apply css using .css() method in jquery